# Flex PopUpManager

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I want to create a pm system with my server. How can i get this to work? here is my concept

```
public function messagePopUp(_userName:String,_target:String,msg:String):void{
//Server sends _userName the person who sent the pm, _target which is you, and a msg (pm)
            if(_target == _username){
//Server checks if you're the _target so popUp will show up
//If it does create the pop up and set window title and the msg in popUp chatTxt text area
                var win:Window = new Window()
                win.title = _userName
                win.chatTxt.text = msg;
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(win,this,false)
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(win);
            }
        }
```

Comment: So this doesn't work? Where's the rest of the code? What's the larger picture?

Comment: It works but how can i call a specifiic window? FOr example if(win.title == "username){win.chatTxt.text += msg}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

Create a panel (mx:titlewindow works) with public vars that you can bind to your UI elements. When you create it, populate it with your values.

Example:  http://www.riacodes.com/flex/build-a-popup-window-with-flex/

So you'd just change your code to:

> var mywin:MyWindowClass = new MyWindowClass();